# Want to subtract two state.selectedDateMillis which are Long?

Tags: kotlin

Here's my snippet with import. Its all Android Studio, I want to subtract two "Long?" and I have no intuition for how to do it. I tried changing them into Long but that doesn't succeed. Please help!

I looked over web and found https://community.appsmith.com/solution/how-find-difference-between-two-dates-datepicker-widgets but I don't understand the moment thing.

```
package com.example.abstinencymeter

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.DisplayMode
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.rememberDatePickerState
import androidx.compose.material3.rememberDateRangePickerState
import androidx.compose.material3.DatePicker
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.abstinencymeter.ui.theme.AbstinencyMeterTheme
import org.jetbrains.annotations.ApiStatus.Experimental
import java.util.Calendar
import kotlin.time.Duration

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AbstinencyMeterTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Column {


                       
                        val state = rememberDatePickerState(
                            initialSelectedDateMillis = 551491200000,
                            initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Input
                        )
                        Text(text = "Od")
                        DatePicker(
                            state = state,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                        )
                        Text(text = "Do")
                        val state2 = rememberDatePickerState(
                            initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Input
                        )
                        DatePicker(
                            state = state2,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `?` means that the value might be `null`. Kotlin, unlike Java, forces you to deal with this problem instead of just letting `null` values propagate through your system. What is `null - 20`? Or `8 - null`? They're not meaningful, so we have to address it.

Option 1 is to provide default values.

```
(a ?: 0) - (b ?: 0)
```

Here, if either value is `null`, we just quietly replace it with a zero.

Alternatively, assuming the variables are `val`s, Kotlin is very clever about recognizing null checks in conditionals. We could write

```
if (a == null || b == null) {
  // Do something special :)
} else {
  return a - b; // Not nullable here!
}
```

If you're absolutely sure the values are non-null, you can assert that.

```
a!! - b!!
```

This will throw an exception if one of them turns out to be `null`. Note that I only recommend this if you know for certain that the values are never `null`. If `null` is actually a valid input, then I recommend throwing a more specific, detailed exception yourself, such as

```
if (a == null || b == null) {
  throw MyCustomExceptionForBadUserInput("Expected non-null timestamps")
} else {
  return a - b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put some conditions on "to" to definie is ass non null and change for String, than back to Long. Thank you all!

```
                        val state = rememberDatePickerState(
                            initialSelectedDateMillis = 551491200000,
                            initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Input
                        )
                        Text(text = "From")
                        DatePicker(
                            state = state,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                        )
                        var od = state.selectedDateMillis.toString()
                        Text(text = "To")
                        val state2 = rememberDatePickerState(
                            initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Input
                        )
                        DatePicker(
                            state = state2,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                        )
                        var _to = state2.selectedDateMillis
                        if (_to != null) {
                            var to = state2.selectedDateMillis.toString()
                            val roznica = od.toLong() - to.toLong()
                            Text(text = "Rożnica: ${roznica}")
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your answer as a start, I see that you're trying to get the difference between two `Long?` nullable values by first calling `toString()` on them and then calling `toLong()`. This is unnecessary, and actually wrong. If a value is `null`, doing `toString()` will return the string "null" and then `toLong()` will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

You should use Kotlin's [null safety feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) instead. Here is the corrected code:

```
                    val state = rememberDatePickerState(
                        initialSelectedDateMillis = 551491200000,
                        initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Input
                    )
                    Text(text = "From")
                    DatePicker(
                        state = state,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                    )
                    var od = state.selectedDateMillis

                    Text(text = "To")
                    val state2 = rememberDatePickerState(
                        initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Input
                    )
                    DatePicker(
                        state = state2,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                    )
                    var to = state2.selectedDateMillis
                    if (to != null && od != null) {
                        // Here, the compiler knows they are non-null Long
                        val roznica = to - od
                        Text(text = "Rożnica: ${roznica}")
                    }
```